# How to convert cv::Mat to MFC CBitmap

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc

how can I convert an OpenCV image to an Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) `CBitmap` object?

I tried the following, which failed,

```
    cv::Mat tmp;
    (Load opencv image ...)

    cv::Size size = tmp.size();
    CBitmap bitmap;
    // 3 colors (RGB), 24bits (8bits*3channels) 
    if (!bitmap.CreateBitmap(128, 128, 1, 24, (void *)tmp.data)) {
        TRACE0("Failed to create bitmap for image display\n");
        return;
    }
```

this results in a black image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://osdir.com/ml/lib.opencv/2006-01/msg00354.html) shares the method of converting an `IplImage` to `CBitmap`:

```
CBitmap* IplImageToCBitmap(IplImage* img) 
{
    CDC dc;
    CDC memDC;

    if (!dc.CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL))
        return NULL;

    if (!memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc))
        return NULL;

    CBitmap* bmp = new CBitmap();
    CBitmap* pOldBitmap;

    bmp->CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, img->width, img->height);
    pOldBitmap = memDC.SelectObject(bmp);

    CvvImage cvImage; // you will need OpenCV_2.2.0- to use CvvImage 
    cvImage.CopyOf(img);
    cvImage.Show(memDC.m_hDC, 0, 0, img->width, img->height, 0, 0);
    cvImage.Destroy();

    memDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);
    memDC.DeleteDC();
    dc.DeleteDC();

    return bmp;
}
```

Based on this, you can achieve your goal by calling it as follows:

```
cv::Mat aMat;
CBitmap *aCBitmap = IplImageToCBitmap((IplImage*) &aMat);
```

Answer (score 0):

the first one convert Mat to CImage after that Attach into CBitmap

```
void Mat2CImage(Mat *mat, CImage &img) {
    if (!mat || mat->empty())
        MessageBox(L"Error convert Mat to CImage", L"error", MB_OK);
    int nBPP = mat->channels() * 8;
    img.Create(mat->cols, mat->rows, nBPP);
    if (nBPP == 8)
    {
        static RGBQUAD pRGB[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            pRGB[i].rgbBlue = pRGB[i].rgbGreen = pRGB[i].rgbRed = i;
        img.SetColorTable(0, 256, pRGB);
    }
    uchar* psrc = mat->data;
    uchar* pdst = (uchar*)img.GetBits();
    int imgPitch = img.GetPitch();
    for (int y = 0; y < mat->rows; y++)
    {
        memcpy(pdst, psrc, mat->cols*mat->channels());//mat->step is incorrect for those images created by roi (sub-images!)
        psrc += mat->step;
        pdst += imgPitch;
    }

    return;
}
```

///////
Using

```
Mat mat_img;
CImage image;
Mat2CImage(&mat_img,image)
CBitmap bitmap;
bitmap.Attach(image.Detach());
```

//--use bitmap
//After done

```
bitmap.Detach();
```