# Passing cv::Mat from C++ to C# (managed)

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, managed, emgucv

I'm writing a wrapper for using C++ code in C#).

I have a function which should return `cv::Mat` back to C#, but I can't find a way to pass the `Mat` to C#.

**Example:**

I'd like to have something like this:

```
cv::Mat MyProject::ReturnColorMat()
{
    return _colorMat;
}
```

I know that C# is working with `Emgu`, is there a conversion between the two?

I tried passing the `byte array` of the `Mat`, and that worked, but I would like to pass the `Mat` itself.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an COM interface in C# and generate an .tlb file out of this that can be used in C++
Like this you can use the same interface for refering to an managed object.

C#

```
  [ComVisible(true)]

   [Guid("12345678-3914-41F0-BB26-122986A93788")]

   [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]

   public interface IMat
   {...}

   public class ManagedMat : IMat
   {...}

  [DllImport("cppProjectname.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern int call2Cpp(IMat obj);
```

C++

```
#import "projectname.tlb" no_registry raw_interfaces_only

// use IMat to access the ManagedMat object
extern "C"  int __declspec(dllexport) call2Cpp( IMat obj )
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Native and managed structures are laid out differently in memory, so successfully passing structures across the managed/unmanaged boundary requires extra steps to preserve data integrity. ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef4c3t39.aspx))
A possibility is to convert cv::Mat to Bitmap in the C++ side and than obtain the Bitmap in C# using PInvoke
In the C++ side you could use this function, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669153/how-to-convert-cvmat-to-mfc-cbitmap)

```
CBitmap* IplImageToCBitmap(IplImage* img) 
{
    CDC dc;
    CDC memDC;

    if (!dc.CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL))
        return NULL;

    if (!memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc))
        return NULL;

    CBitmap* bmp = new CBitmap();
    CBitmap* pOldBitmap;

    bmp->CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, img->width, img->height);
    pOldBitmap = memDC.SelectObject(bmp);

    CvvImage cvImage; // you will need OpenCV_2.2.0- to use CvvImage 
    cvImage.CopyOf(img);
    cvImage.Show(memDC.m_hDC, 0, 0, img->width, img->height, 0, 0);
    cvImage.Destroy();

    memDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);
    memDC.DeleteDC();
    dc.DeleteDC();

    return bmp;
}
```

and then wrap your function in this way

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport) HRESULT WrappedFunction(HBITMAP * hBitmap);

HRESULT WrappedFunction(/*[out]*/ HBITMAP * hBitmap)
{
    cv::Mat aMat = YourFunction();

    CBitmap *bmp = IplImageToCBitmap((IplImage*) &aMat);

    *hBitmap = (HBITMAP)bmp->Detach();

    return S_OK;
}
```

Then, in the C# side you could do:

```
IntPtr ret;
WrappedFunction( out ret );
Bitmap b = Image.FromHbitmap( ret );
```