# use c++ function that returns Mat in c# and convert it to bitmap

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

i've written a function in c++ and the function returns a Mat.then I build a dll file from c++ file and use the function in c# windows application.I guess because it doesn't get converted to Bitmap the picturebox doesn't show anything and it is still empty.
here is the c++ code:

```
#define MyFunctions _declspec(dllexport)

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

extern "C" {    

    MyFunctions Mat getFrame()
    {
        Mat frame;
        //--- INITIALIZE VIDEOCAPTURE
        VideoCapture cap;
        // open the default camera using default API
        // cap.open(0);
        // OR advance usage: select any API backend
        int deviceID = 0;             // 0 = open default camera
        int apiID = cv::CAP_ANY;      // 0 = autodetect default API
                                      // open selected camera using selected API
        cap.open(deviceID, apiID);
        // check if we succeeded
        if (!cap.isOpened()) {
            cerr << "ERROR! Unable to open camera\n";
        }
        //--- GRAB AND WRITE LOOP
        cout << "Start grabbing" << endl
            << "Press any key to terminate" << endl;

        // wait for a new frame from camera and store it into 'frame'
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            // wait for a new frame from camera and store it into 'frame'
            cap.read(frame);
            // check if we succeeded
            if (frame.empty()) {
                cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
                break;
            }
            // show live and wait for a key with timeout long enough to show images
            imshow("Live", frame);
            if (waitKey(5) >= 0)
                break;
        }
        // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
        return frame;
    }
}
```

and here is the c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace MyForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public const string CppFunctionsDLL = @"..\..\..\x64\Debug\cpp.dll";

        [DllImport(CppFunctionsDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Mat getFrame();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Mat mat = new Mat();
            mat = getFrame(); 
            Image<Bgr, byte> image = mat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
            Bitmap bm = image.ToBitmap();
            
            pictureBox1.Image = bm;
        }
    }
}
```

any solutions on how to get it to be shown on picturebox?
thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know `Emgu.CV` but I'd be pretty surprised if returning an object from a c++ function by value works correctly with it

Comment: do you you any other way that I can do this

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866873/passing-cvmat-from-c-to-c-sharp-managed. Looking at the emgu interfaces there doesn't seem to be any public method to convert from a native `Mat` to an emgu `Mat`

Comment: It would be easier for you to write the whole code in C#.